# Tweet Particular text Using links on twitter

Tags: facebook, twitter

i am using the below code to send the some text on facebook . Is there any code similar to tweet a some text on twitter?

```
<a title="send to Facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=YOUR_TITLE&p[summary]=YOUR_SUMMARY&p[url]=YOUR_URL&p[images][0]=YOUR_IMAGE_TO_SHARE_OBJECT" target="_blank"><span><img width="14" height="14" src="" /> Share</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Try:

```
 <a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=http://www.test.com&text=Test">Tweet</a>
```